# Windows Internet Explorer 8 Dynamic Installer category in WSUS

Tags: wsus, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm new to WSUS and I'm in the process of setting up a WSUS server. I'm wondering what is meant by the "Windows Internet Explorer 7/8 Dynamic Installer" category under "Under Products And Classifications"? Will this allow me to push out updates for IE 7/8 or will it also push out upgrades from IE6 or IE7 to IE7 or IE8. We're running IE7 at the moment, and want to avoid upgrading to IE8 at this point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dynamic Installer category is detected by the IE7/IE8 installation process, and is installed then - it is used to make sure the IE7/IE8 gets updated with the latest patches at the time of installation.

The actual IE7/IE8 installers are in the "Update Rollups" classification in WSUS, and you would need to push that for IE8 to be installed. (That being said, it doesn't make any sense to push the Dynamic Installer for IE8 if you aren't pushing IE8.)

As long as you are pushing all of the updates for IE7 and IE8 when you jump to it, in all of the standard update classifications, you should be OK without pushing the Dynamic Installer at all.

Comment: We do have a handful of IE8 users. So we would want to keep them up to date.